# WebMethod In Aspx Page Can Not Have access Allow-Origin

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have following code.It is not working for enabling CORS.Please help.I am not able to enable CORS in my Web Method on aspx page :

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Response.AppendHeader("access-control-allow-headers", "content-type");
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod] 
        public static string Get(string data)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("access-control-allow-headers", "content-type");
            return data + " 123";
        }

    }

    // Java Script


    function GetData() {
    window.jQuery.support.cors = true;
    window.jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://generalservices.prop.preview.gearhost.com//Default.aspx/Get',

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        data: "{ data : '12'}",
        success: function (d) {

        },
        error: function (d) {

        }
    });
```

> error :  in Access-Control-Allow-Origin not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page methods are supposed to be used only from the same page where they are defined.

If you need to fetch data from different pages, I would suggest you look into `Asp.Net Web api`. Or you could even create a simple `Generic handler` (`.ashx` file) which you call from your page(s). The handler could deserialize the Json data, process it and return the required response. In a generic handler you can specify any/all http headers that you need.

Comment: thanks for recommended but this is old version code and we dont want change it

Comment: Generic handlers have been around since Asp.Net version 1.